# How to do a major content change in Drupal without users knowing

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, url-rewriting

I operate a **drupal 6** website for my business and it does just as I want.

Only I am planning a major update in which I will be changing the theme and most of my pages. I would like to know how I could basically change all the pages, but only publish the changes when I'm ready (if possible)?

I thought about creating a whole new Drupal website and then moving it to do my desired directory but then I would lose everything else in my database (like orders) and all  my extensive settings which can not happen!

I would not like to make the 'site off-line' for maintainence either because the website is perfectly functional as it is and I need as much chance for visitors and publicity as possible!

So if any knows of a solution for my situation it would be much appriciated if you could tell me!

Thanks in Advance,

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your site international? Have a look at your analytics - is there not a time of day when your site has significantly less, or even approaching zero, users? This will be much harder in an international site, but look at your stats and see if there is a regular slump when you can perform this update.

I would create the new site along side the existing, and when ready update the dns, or point the virtual host to the new folder and then copy the orders table (and anything else you need) to the new database as @jmkeyes suggested.

Comment: in regards to your first paragraph its hard to say really. The site isnt actual availabe to the public as yet (but I hope it will be in the next few days). Anyhow, I think your next solution and @jmkeyes' suggestion will work for me - just a couple of questions... 1) Is it really as easy as copying the nessecary tables from one MySQL database to the other? 2) If so, is it possible to just copy the content tables from the new site to the old one so I don't have to mess around moving files?

Comment: I think I may have found the ultimate solution for me ( but I am still interested in the answers to my previous two questions)! I found the Node Export module for Drupal 6. I can't see any outstanding problems so far, it even allows import and export in bulk. It's a bit dodgey at custom urls but what am going to do is put the website in maintenance mode once I am ready to import the new nodes I exported from a different drupal site and check everything is okay therefore minimizing the amount of down time etc...! Thanks for everyones help though

Answer (score 3):

You could upload your Drupal 6 theme to /sites/all/themes/ and when you're ready to deploy it, just switch the theme in your settings and flush the caches. All of your content should remain the same as it was.

If you have significant changes to the Drupal installation in the update, maintenance mode is probably your best option. It was provided so that users would know there was an upgrade going on and to prevent users from making changes that would be destroyed between the time of the last backup and and the re-launch of the web site.

If maintenance mode really does not work (and you need to hide information from your users) I'd create a script to copy all orders and other volatile data to the new website immediately at launch. It's a hack, yes, but there really isn't another option.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. Thanks for the suggestion but maintenance is not ideal for me and the theme thing is what I am/was going to do anyway! I don't mind hacks but I wouldn't really call idea a hack - just a great idea I may put into action

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same tables, you can essentially have them both up and just change dns if on a different server, or change the htaccess settings to point at a site on the same server.

Comment: Hi Scott, I don't really understand your suggestion. I interpret it as 'create another drupal website connected to the same database and then switch the old one with the new one when it is ready'. If so, surely when I changed the content on the new drupal site it woukd change it on the old one too seeing as they are both using the same data source!? Anyway, I think I have found a solution already but thanks a bunch anyway

Answer (score 0):

The way I interpret your question, you want to keep the data from your existing site and have as small a window of downtime while migrating to the modified site.

First ensure that your site uses a drupal sub-directory off the document root (as opposed to installing Drupal directly within the document root). This will allow you to switch between sites without your users knowing anything is up.
This requires the following .htaccess file in the base directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) drupal6/$1 [L]
```

Note that `drupal6` needs to be replaced with what ever directory name you choose to install your various D6 installations.
It also requires that the `sites/default/settings.php` has the variable $base_url defined.
If your settings.php file is defined somewhere else, then modify it in that location.

I would recommend that you backup the data from the existing site and use it on your new site (it should be compatible I would hope). If not you might need to have the same module and theme set, but disable the un-required modules/themes as needed.
Using your existing site data, you can restructure your development site as required.

When you are ready to go live with the revised site do the following:

- take the existing site offline and perform a backup of the data.
- using the backup, restore the data onto the new site.
- test that the new site is still functional.
- change the base .htaccess file to point to the new site.

This should make your downtime very short (particularly if you have tested your new site with the existing sites data prior to the switch over). It will also give you future flexibility when upgrading to new versions of Drupal core (e.g. D7).

Comment: You have interpreted my question correctly but your solution has a couple of flaws in it for me, which the last solution I found (Node Export) doesn't. The problem with a site switch over like you said, is that I would have to create a new MySQL and reconstruct settings, meaning I would lose order info & more etc. therefore it would just be easier to do as I said in my second comment to simon and export/import the nodes I need to change etc!